# Pandas: group with 10T but to have a 00:11:00 format

Tags: python, pandas

after this

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='10T')
```

I will have datetime groups like

```
2017-05-17 13:20:00
2017-05-17 13:30:00
```

I want to archieve this particular format:

```
2017-05-17 13:21:00
2017-05-17 13:31:00
```

How I can make this trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need parameter `base` which can found in [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-05-17 13:21:00', periods=10, freq='10T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (df)
   a            datetime
0  0 2017-05-17 13:21:00
1  1 2017-05-17 13:31:00
2  2 2017-05-17 13:41:00
3  3 2017-05-17 13:51:00
4  4 2017-05-17 14:01:00
5  5 2017-05-17 14:11:00
6  6 2017-05-17 14:21:00
7  7 2017-05-17 14:31:00
8  8 2017-05-17 14:41:00
9  9 2017-05-17 14:51:00

a = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='10T', base=1)).sum()
print (a)
                     a
datetime              
2017-05-17 13:21:00  0
2017-05-17 13:31:00  1
2017-05-17 13:41:00  2
2017-05-17 13:51:00  3
2017-05-17 14:01:00  4
2017-05-17 14:11:00  5
2017-05-17 14:21:00  6
2017-05-17 14:31:00  7
2017-05-17 14:41:00  8
2017-05-17 14:51:00  9
```

---

```
a = df.resample('10T', on='datetime', base=1).sum()
print (a)
                     a
datetime              
2017-05-17 13:21:00  0
2017-05-17 13:31:00  1
2017-05-17 13:41:00  2
2017-05-17 13:51:00  3
2017-05-17 14:01:00  4
2017-05-17 14:11:00  5
2017-05-17 14:21:00  6
2017-05-17 14:31:00  7
2017-05-17 14:41:00  8
2017-05-17 14:51:00  9
```

Comment: Well, it seems great, but I do not see 'base' parameter in pandas documentation (v0.20.1)